# parseSdk content failed in Eclipse for android development

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to create android project but i am getting the following error. The error is shown in the first error below[image: The error is shown in image]

If i continue for creating project its also showing error in the project. The error is shown in the second image below.[image: The Error after creating project is shown in the second image]

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete Android 5 ( API 21 ) installed packages from SDK Manager.
It worked for me. I am using Android 4.4W.2 (API 20).

This must be helpful for you
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Z5iXn3N8sU